# Deleting SCIP constraints

Tags: segmentation-fault, constraints, scip

I'm trying to look for the **constraint that causes infeasible solution**. For that I'm applying **delCons()** method of the SCIP model, which throughs me an **segfault** error. I'm using pyscipopt wrapper for python.  The issue is: how to **delete constraints** if possible? And is there any other way to analyze constraints to find infeasibility reasons (something like minIISC)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to delete a constraint in this way. Did you ensure that the constraint that you pass to the `delCons` method extually exists / is not `NULL`?

Comment: the point here was that I called `delCons` method with list of constraints passed, and this list was just appended by constraints at the creation time. This way it doesn't work,
However, when I call `getConss` and to get the list of constraints and then deletion works.

Comment: Hey, @Leon! Following up on what the original poster asked, is there a standard way to discover which constraint caused infeasibility?